# Device connected to local network with IPv6 despite noipv6 setting

Tags: linux, debian, network-interface, dhcp, lan

In `dhcpconf.conf` file I have set `noipv6` in the section of interface used for the connection, in past this apparently worked, now the device has assigned both IPv4 and IPv6 as I can se from inet6 address in `ifconfig` output, and if I try to connect to it from another device in the network using IPv6, it connects correctly with the IPv6 assigned normally.

How I can make sure only IPv4 is assigned?

Comment: Do you want the full ipv6 subsystem to be disabled?

Comment: @NicolasFormichella It's enough that it is connected in the local network always with IPv4 only, if it is possible without disabling the whole ipv6 subsystem completely.

Comment: See [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/IPv6#Disable_functionality) @AndreaF

Comment: @NicolasFormichella thanks for the tip, however this disables all ipv6 stack. Is possible to prevent dhcp to assign ipv6 without disabling whole ipv6 stack?

Comment: Yes there is see the `ipv6.disable_ipv6=1` option

Comment: ok. I will try.